# allow only chars as user input and assign them to variables?

Tags: java

I have this task where I have to handle some user input. The user should only be able to enter a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l and after the user input I want to assign a,b,c..l to variables 0,1,2,3,4..,11. Every other input, except for capital letters should give an error - but how can I do this?

I got as far as this:

```
int number;

public String playerInput;  

public void start()
{       
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    System.out.println("please enter input:");
    playerInput = scn.nextLine();       
    System.out.println("scn.nextLine() = " +playerInput);
}
```

I really don't know how I would be able to just store mentioned letters and assign them to variables, can someone help?

Comment: a) Why do you need an int for every possible character? b) Just scan a string and take the first character. You can ignore the rest (or display an error message) then you can use lots of `if`-`else` or convert it to ASCII and check that it's between 65 and 77 (uppercase) or 97 and 109 (lowercase). Use `char` data type

Comment: Call `toLower` on each input string. Subtract 'a' from your character read to get the 0-based equivalent. Make an `int[26]` array. Check that the input is between 0 and 25, throw an exception if it isn't. Fill the array with the values.

Comment: Capital letters means only `A B C D E F G H I J K L` or include other capital letters ???.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it unclear what you meant by Assiging it to variable from number.

so here i'm giving you idea how to just input char between a-l and then you can do the things with you input

```
public class CharInput {

    public static void main(String... str) throws IOException {

        // open Scanner for input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input");
        //since you want only lowercase as input so converting at front is an better option
        String playerInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

        // to make sure we have only char input nothing else
        char input = playerInput.charAt(0);

        // Check if the inputted char is between a and l only
        if (input >= 'a' && input <='l' ){

    // Do the stuff you want to do if the input is in between
    // with the char variable input
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error Raised");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `(int)input >= 97` just do `input >= 'a'` (same for upper bound). Might be clearer.

Comment: how would I make this repeat itself when you give the wrong input?

Comment: thanks, that's what I've been trying to do but somehow I can't make it work, would you care to show me how, I keep getting bugs..?

Comment: anyways help me if you want, eitherway your answer was very helpful thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Prog {

int[] array = new int[12];
 Set<String> list = new HashSet<String>();
 String alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L";
 int count = 0 ;
 public String playerInput;  

 public void start() throws Exception
 {  
   String[] val =  alphabet.split(",");
   while(count<24){

        list.add(val[count]);
        count++;     
   }     
   Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in ); 
   while(count < 12){
        System.out.println("please enter input:");
        playerInput = scn.nextLine();       
        System.out.println("scn.nextLine() = " + playerInput);

        if(list.contains(playerInput)){
           //assign your desired value to that letter
        }
        else{
           //throw exception here ;
        }
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: Uncompilable code without any explanation? This almost always a bad answer :(.

Comment: explain uncompilable  @Tom
this was section of code , were you expecting import statments too  ? :)

Comment: "explain uncompilable" very easy: take your code and post it in your IDE, then you will see. And _no_, I'm not talking about import statements.

Comment: This better, but still no explanation for OP :P.

Comment: Haven't  you seen some comments in the snippet .
was it saying something ?
Compiler doesn't take comments seriously .  :(

Comment: Yes I see the two comments there, but this doesn't explain what you're doing there. Since OP seems to be very new, I don't think he understands your code.

Comment: Isn't Collections is too way ahead going by the standard of the OP questions and i agree with @Tom .. OP won't understand this

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your problem clearly but i guess may be you want to do something like this(not sure though) -

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in ); 
System.out.println("please enter input:");
playerInput = scn.nextLine();
int i=0;

Map<String,Integer> map=new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
Set<String> set= new TreeSet<String>();

while(playerInput.matches("[a-lA-L]")){
    set.add(playerInput.toLowerCase());
    playerInput=scn.nextLine();
    if(!playerInput.matches("[a-lA-L]")){
        System.out.println("Error!!! Wrong Input");
        break;
    }
    }
for(String s:set){
    map.put(s, i);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(map);
```